# How to use webdings character map in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to use webdings characters in .net application.
Does anyone know how to do this.

I tried using :

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSample" runat="server" Font-Names="Webdings" ></asp:Label>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
lblSample.Text = "0x61"
```

But it doesn't displaying properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in any [ASCII table](http://bluesock.org/~willg/dev/ascii.html), character `0x61` is a lower case `a`.

You are trying to output the string `"0x61"` instead of a lower case `a`.

You should be doing this:

```
lblSample.Text = "a"
```